OSX Sequoia: Can't enable hardware flow control on USB/serial devices
I'm currently trying to use a USB/serial device on an M2 Mac running OSX Sequoia to communicate with an older oscilloscope that requires hardware flow control. For some reason, I can't seem to enable this mode on any device or with any serial client I try. I've attempted several different serial devices, including an FTDI and a Prologic that displays LEDs for the enabled lines, and several clients including screen/cu/minicom/picocom. Picocom provides the most useful feedback, in that when I try to start it with hardware flow control enabled, it informs me that there is a !! Settings mismatch !! and the flow control settings display flow: RTS/CTS (none). I've also tried to enable hardware flow control via stty, invoking stty -f /dev/<serial_port> crtscts, but when I check the status with -a, I still see -crtscts.
When I use these same devices on a Ubuntu machine, I am able to enable hardware flow control with no issues, so I'm thinking this is some kind of OS issue, but I can't really understand how that could be the case.

This, maybe? https://github.com/manuelbl/usb-serial/blob/master/README.md
